# Capture, store and retrieve photo in activity

Tags: java, android, image, capture

I have a problem, that I can't fix. I have spent almost all day today trying to get this to work, but I can't and I am out of any ideas, so decided to ask for your help.

Also, I have looked around google and stackoverflow for answers, none of which helped me.

The problem regards photo capturing with android. I have an activity, where I can "create" a new item that is later on stored in a database. I can pass it a name and location, as well as take a photo that binds to it. When I press "add" it is saved to the database. Everything works, except the Camera intent. I want to be able to take a photo in that activity, that binds to the "object" I'm creating, so later on I can view that photo when I click on a particular "object" on a list. I do have permissions (write and read) in my AndroidManifest, but still they dont help.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18"
    />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                 android:maxSdkVersion="18"
    />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
              android:required="false"
    />
```

My android version is 6.0.
This code is the most recent compilation of solutions that I have gathered to try to make it work. I would very much appreciate your help with my issue.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class CreateItemFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int REQUEST_PHOTO = 2;
    private static final String TAG = "button clicked";
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    private TextView mNameText;
    private TextView mLocationText;
    private Button mAddButton;
    private ImageButton mPhotoButton;
    private ImageView mPhotoView;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;
    private File mPhotoFile;
    private Item mItem;
    private List<Item> mItems;
    private static ItemStash sItemStash;

    public static CreateItemFragment newInstance(){
        return new CreateItemFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_item, container, false);

        mNameText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        mLocationText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_location);
        sItemStash = sItemStash.get(getContext());


        mAddButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mAddButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mNameText.getText().length() > 0 && mLocationText.getText().length() > 0){
                    sItemStash.addItem(
                            new Item(mNameText.getText().toString(),
                                    mLocationText.getText().toString()));
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mNameText.getText().toString() + " added to the list!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mNameText.setText("");
                mLocationText.setText("");

            }
        });

        mPhotoButton = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.photo_button);
        //final Intent captureImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        /*
        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        boolean canTakePhoto = mPhotoFile != null && captureImage.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null;
        mPhotoButton.setEnabled(canTakePhoto);

        if(canTakePhoto) {
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(mPhotoFile);
            captureImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        }
        */

        mPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                verifyStoragePermissions(getActivity());
                capturePhotoIntent();
                //startActivityForResult(captureImage, REQUEST_PHOTO);
                //mPhotoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString());
                //mPhotoFile = new File(mItem.setPhotoFilename(mNameText.getText().toString()));
            }


        });

        mPhotoView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_photo);
        //updatePhotoView();

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)extras.get("data");
            //mPhotoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString());
            mPhotoView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }


    }

    /*
    private void updatePhotoView(){
        if(mPhotoFile == null || !mPhotoFile.exists()){
            Log.d(TAG, "is clicked");
            mPhotoView.setImageDrawable(null);
        }else{
            Bitmap bitmap = PhotoUtils.getScaledBitmap(mPhotoFile.getPath(), getActivity());
            mPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
    */

    private void capturePhotoIntent(){
        Intent photoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        if(photoIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null){
            File photoFile = null;
            try{
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            }catch (IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(photoFile != null) {
                photoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(photoIntent, REQUEST_PHOTO);
            }

        }
    }

    public File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        verifyStoragePermissions(getActivity());

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );

        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
        int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    activity,
                    PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
        }
    }







}
```

*EDIT
Forgot to paste in my stack trace. I do get this:

```
04-21 22:34:56.688 3574-3604/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp 

W/OpenGLRenderer: Fail to change FontRenderer cache size, it already initialized
04-21 22:34:56.704 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp D/android.widget.GridLayout: horizontal constraints: x1-x0>=163, x2-x1>=1080, x2-x0<=1080 are inconsistent; permanently removing: x2-x0<=1080. 
04-21 22:34:56.708 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp D/android.widget.GridLayout: vertical constraints: y2-y0>=745, y2-y1<=136, y1-y0<=136 are inconsistent; permanently removing: y2-y1<=136. 
04-21 22:34:56.819 3574-3604/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb8767340
04-21 22:34:57.533 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err: java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:939)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:1004)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp.CreateItemFragment.createImageFile(CreateItemFragment.java:173)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp.CreateItemFragment.capturePhotoIntent(CreateItemFragment.java:154)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp.CreateItemFragment.access$300(CreateItemFragment.java:30)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp.CreateItemFragment$2.onClick(CreateItemFragment.java:108)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5226)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21266)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 22:34:57.538 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
04-21 22:34:57.539 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
04-21 22:34:57.539 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-21 22:34:57.539 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-21 22:34:57.539 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
04-21 22:34:57.539 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:     at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:932)
04-21 22:34:57.539 3574-3574/com.bignerdranch.android.tingleapp W/System.err:   ... 14 more
```

the method verisfyStoragePermission() was supposed to fix that error as I found in other topics, but I still get this error

Comment: In what way is the _Camera Intent_ not working? e.g. What results do you get, if an error then you will likely be asked for the stack trace, as this often helps to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: When I press the button, nothing happens, and I get this error - open failed: EACCES (Permission denied). So to my understanding, android doesnt let me create a new file, which I need to do.